# Optimize express.js app - keep-alive is not enabled

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, keep-alive, node-http-proxy

I have express.js app hosted on ubuntu server via node-http-proxy (https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)

I've run the app on http://www.webpagetest.org/ and receive warning that I should enable "Keep-alive" in my app.

I need advice from someone experienced in that topic, how can I enable it?